# asp.net 2.0 site and location of <script/> tags causing problems/conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, script-tag

I have no idea how to describe this accurately/intelligently because it seems to be completely impossible, yet there must some reason for it.

I am trying to leverage jquery, jquery-ui, qtip (tooltip for jquery) and highcharts (javascript charting), but for purpose of post I could just as easily been only using jQuery and jQuery-UI.

If I include my `<script/>` tags at the bottom of my `<head/>` element I get an error trying to call the .slider() extension to configure my sliders.  But if I put the `<script/>` tags right before the closing of my `<body/>` element then everything works.  To illustrate, the following will not work (obviously some pseudo code below):

```
  <head>
    <script jquery.js/>
    <script jquery-ui.js/>
  </head>
  <body>
     ... html ...
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".slider").slider( { .. options .. } );
       } )
     </script>
     ... more html *including* the .slider elements
  </body>
```

However, if I move the two jQuery script tags to be right above the `</body>` closing element things work.  When the script tags are in the head element and I debug my application, basically the page *does* appear to have completely loaded and Visual Studio highlights the line calling the .slider() function saying it doesn't know what slider() is.  Looking at the call stack, it appears to be correctly calling it from the document ready function...the mark up all appears to be there as well, making me believe the document truly is ready.

Now I didn't include things that are required by asp.net 1.1/2.0 site in my pseudo code, namely a `<form/>` element with runat="server' and the use of a `<asp:ScriptManager/>` tag (we needed that for parsing monetary values from different cultures leveraging Microsoft Ajax).  I can't believe they would be causing the problem, but maybe they are.  Additionally, asp.net injects several of its own script sections (i.e. for validation, post back, etc.)

Regarding the form tag...all the html and document.ready markup would be *inside* the form tag, while the script tags are *always* outside of the form tag (either above it, in the head or below it at the bottom of the body).

Obviously I could leave the script tags at the bottom, and I very well may end up doing that, but I am trying to get a clean 'template site' of which to use when creating new client sites and it just feels wrong that I have a restriction forcing me to put those tags at the bottom of the html.  I'm sure our framework code (or maybe asp.net's) is simply inserting something that is causing problems/conflicts with jQuery, but I don't really know how to go about debugging/diagnosing what that problem is.  So if anyone has any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Does adding the `defer` attribute to your script block in the `head` tag make any difference?

Comment: Hmm, yes it does.  I like that better than putting tags at end of body, but still feels like an unneeded hack.  Do you know what that might indicate (the fact that it fixes the problem)?

Comment: Any particular version of jQuery you're using? And does this problem occur in other browsers?

Comment: Was using jQuery 1.4.4.  Didn't think to check that.  So I upgraded to 1.6.1 (another of our more recent projects had already been updated) and now it is back to not working even with defer attributes on there.  And yes it happens in other browsers.  Note, I'm not even sure what the current release version of jQuery is.

Comment: If you could provide a link to your page, this would be a whole lot easier to debug.

Comment: Working version: https://www.demo.buckapplications.com/decisiontools/fsa/default.aspx    Non working version: https://www.demo.buckapplications.com/decisiontools/fsa/default.aspx?head=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jQuery 1.3.2 is being loaded by ASP.NET (see your second WebResource.axd). The two library versions are overwriting each other. Thus the reason it works when you load 1.6.2 at the end of the page.

Comment: Wow, some low level component was injecting 1.3.2 jQuery.  Thanks for spotting that.  So removing that and putting script includes at top fixed problem.  Next question.  Now that I've figured that out, I've seen several comments/patterns to place all script includes at bottom of body element for performance reasons.  Is this the recommended practice?  Also, doing that, any $(document) ready blocks I have have to come after the include right?

Comment: I always tend to put them in the head but I could see putting at the bottom as a benefit if you want your content to load as quickly as possible. In the case of the form that you have I would not see the benefit of loading after the content because the form is pretty heavily reliant on the jquery library for sliders, interaction, graphs and such.